# How can I loop through a two-dimensional array and display the values if another value is true?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have an array like:

```
0
name => 'john',
age => '99',
isTheOne => boolean true

1
name => 'Jeff',
age => '88',
isTheOne => boolean false
```

What I need to do is, for each row in the array, only display its contents if the field `isTheOne` is `true`.

I thought I'd need to use a `while` loop to do this, but I'm a bit stuck. I don't know how to move forward with this?

Comment: Show us your code. Isn't it just something like `for(..) { if ($array[$i]['isTheOne'] == true) { // print array }}`?

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $array = array(
                0 => array(
                    "name" => 'john',
                    "age" => '99',
                    "isTheOne" => true
                ),

                1 => array(
                    "name" => 'Jeff',
                    "age" => '88',
                    "isTheOne" => false
                )
            );

    foreach($array as $subarray) {
        foreach($subarray as $k => $v) {
            if($k == "isTheOne" && $v == TRUE)
                echo "Key: " . $k . " Value: " . $v;
        }
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
Key: isTheOne Value: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**array_map()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead of loop. Example:

```
$arr= array(
    array(
        "name" => 'john',
        "age" => '99',
        "isTheOne" => true,
    ),
    array(
        "name" => 'Jeff',
        "age" => '88',
        "isTheOne" => false,
    )
);

array_map(function($v){
    if(isset($v['isTheOne']) && $v['isTheOne']) echo 'TheOne is true <br />';
}, $arr);
```

Using `foreach()`

```
foreach($arr as $val){
    if(isset($val['isTheOne']) && $val['isTheOne'])
        echo 'TheOne is True <br />';
}
```